# How do I stream different partitions in parallel in ZIO Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, zio

I have a Kafka architecture program and want to stream different partitions in parallel on each consumer instance, do I use the mapNPar or should I create different consumer instances and then fork them and join them in a for flat map?

Comment: how did you end up solving this @khalilkm01 ?